# What is the best way to handle delta sync for calendar long term synchronization on Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

We plan to synchronize the resource calendar using the "calendarView delta" method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

We have found that it is possible to synchronize a calendar without specifying a start and end date, but for now this feature is in beta.

What is the best way to retrieve the events of a future period, while time is running? For example, if we want to retrieve the events of the coming year, we need to create a delta [today, year +1], but next month this delta, encrypted in the token, will represent the period [month -1, month + 11] .

We thought of a solution that would consist in renewing the token every month, but this has two drawbacks: it forces us to run a full synchronization once a month for all synchronized resources, and we don't really synchronize a sliding one-year window.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you find a solution?

I'm considering 2 options.

Setting the end date to a long time in the future (I tried 50 years and that worked, but I've not found any official documentation on what the max end date is).

Storing separate delta urls for each calendar year, so we might want events sync'd 4 years in advance so I'd setup 4 separate syncs with 4 delta urls and when the next year ticks over I would drop the oldest sync and create a new one

Comment: @dirtbag For the moment we have set the end date at 4 years in the future, which seems reasonable for our use cases. We will plan periodic tasks that will renew the period regularly, perhaps every year because it is a rather expensive operation that will require a complete synchronization of resources